# Limit when using UNION ALL and LEFT JOINs

Tags: php, mysql

Apparently when using UNION or UNION ALL the performance is affected. My page loads 5-10x faster when I'm not using UNION or UNION ALL. I would like to add a LIMIT to the query to help with the performance issue.

The problem is when i add LIMIT 5, i'm only getting 5 records from the first SELECT. I need 5 records for each SELECT. So in total I should have 15 records.

Here's an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3617ee/6

Comment: limit work on result  .. you select all the rows in each subquery however..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use limit on individual select queries within `UNION`, wrap them in parentheses. From [`Union`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) documentation:

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause
>   inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT

One more interesting point:

> However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies
>   nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result
>   because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows. Therefore,
>   the use of ORDER BY in this context is typically in conjunction with
>   LIMIT, so that it is used to determine the subset of the selected rows
>   to retrieve for the SELECT, even though it does not necessarily affect
>   the order of those rows in the final UNION result. **If ORDER BY appears
>   without LIMIT in a SELECT, it is optimized away because it will have
>   no effect anyway.**

[Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3617ee/7)

```
(
SELECT 

openservicecalls.serial,
openservicecalls.company,

product1_errors.serial,
product1_errors.error,

description.error,
description.description,

masterlist.serial,
masterlist.phonenumber

FROM product1_errors
LEFT JOIN description
ON product1_errors.error = description.error
LEFT JOIN openservicecalls
ON product1_errors.serial = openservicecalls.serial
LEFT JOIN masterlist
ON product1_errors.serial = masterlist.serial LIMIT 5
)

UNION ALL

(
SELECT 

openservicecalls.serial,
openservicecalls.company,

product2_errors.serial,
product2_errors.error,

description.error,
description.description,

masterlist.serial,
masterlist.phonenumber

FROM product2_errors
LEFT JOIN description
ON product2_errors.error = description.error
LEFT JOIN openservicecalls
ON product2_errors.serial = openservicecalls.serial
LEFT JOIN masterlist
ON product2_errors.serial = masterlist.serial LIMIT 5
)

UNION ALL

(
 SELECT 

openservicecalls.serial,
openservicecalls.company,

product3_errors.serial,
product3_errors.error,

description.error,
description.description,

masterlist.serial,
masterlist.phonenumber

FROM product3_errors
LEFT JOIN description
ON product3_errors.error = description.error
LEFT JOIN openservicecalls
ON product3_errors.serial = openservicecalls.serial
LEFT JOIN masterlist
ON product3_errors.serial = masterlist.serial  LIMIT 5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `LIMIT` to each `SELECT` statment and wrap all queries in parentheses

```
(SELECT *
FROM table1
LIMIT 5)

UNION ALL
(SELECT *
FROM table2
LIMIT 5)

UNION ALL
(SELECT *
FROM table3
LIMIT 5)
```